# Using jQuery in Angular (TypeScript, Webpack)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I have an Angular (v2) project using TypeScript and Webpack. I used some starter project for seed, but the configuration has been so heavily modified it does not matter to point to the source now.

I'd like to use jQuery in my project. Reference to `jquery-3.2.0.min.js` was already in the main `index.html` file, as it is required by Bootstrap. So, the references to `$` in my scripts do not break the typescript compilation. I get `Cannot find module 'jquery'.` error, although there is `import * as $ from 'jquery';` line at the top of the respective typescript file. However, the code still runs because of the jQuery `<script>` reference in the `index.html`.

Well, I wanted to do this properly, so I went ahead and installed both the jQuery library and the types for jQuery:

```
$ npm install --save jquery
$ npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

To my horror, right after adding the jQuery types, the compilation now is riddled with loads of errors, 7140 in total. Here's a small excerpt below:

```
ERROR in [default] /[path]/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:35:22 
Generic type 'JQueryStatic<TElement, HTMLElement>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] /[path]/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:36:17 
Generic type 'JQueryStatic<TElement, HTMLElement>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] /[path]/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:43:45 
',' expected.

ERROR in [default] /[path]/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:54:11 
Generic type 'EventStatic<TTarget, EventTarget>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] /[path]/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:62:14 
Generic type 'PlainObject<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] /[path]/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:70:15 
Generic type 'PlainObject<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] /[path]/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:71:17 
Generic type 'JQuery<TElement, HTMLElement>' requires 2 type argument(s).
```

If I uninstall the types, I get back to the more-friendlier `Cannot find module 'jquery'.` error.

I have tried with different combinations of node `jquery` and `@types/jquery` versions to no avail.

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../dist",
    "rootDir": "../src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "core-js"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

I have tried adding `jquery` to the `types`, or changing the `target` to `es6`, but no luck.

I am out of options here. I can survive with `<script>` declaration in the root `index.html`, but that's just not right. Obviously I am missing something here.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here: is "jQuery as a module" compatible with commonjs modules? Or do you need AMD / es2016 module syntax? Also, have you tried compiling a simple test that ONLY uses jQuery as a module (no angular or anything else, just to see if the types / modules are working at all).

Comment: check this [Third Party JS](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) link might help

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any of the extra efforts you have done.

just replace:

`import * as $ from 'jquery'`

with

`declare var $:any;`

Comment: Yes, that makes the `Cannot find module` error go away. But it still requires referencing the jQuery js file in the root index.html. It's not exactly how things ought to be done in the Angular-node-typescript world, kinda feels wrong.

Comment: you can install jquery npm module and require it in the main.ts file